FunctionConvexity of power function $x^a$
I'm trying to check convexity of some functions. I encoundered a problem with the line
FunctionConvexity[x^a, x, Assumptions -> {a > 0}]
(* FunctionConvexity[x^a, x, Assumptions -> {a > 0}] *)

as if checking convexity when the exponent is a parameter didn't work, it just returns the input.
However, in the same notebook, it did return a result for a function that also had an exponent that was a parameter. The result was Indeterminate.
Now I'm wondering what is happening: Is $x^a$ with a parameter as an exponent not a valid input, or is the result Indeterminate wrong?

First, the question under consideration makes sense only for positive values of x because in the general case x^a can take complex values (for example, ComplexExpand[(-2)^Sqrt[2]] // N performs -0.709609 - 2.56894 I.
Second, the case a>0 should be split in the two cases:
FunctionConvexity[{x^a,x>=0},x,Assumptions->a>=1]


1

FunctionConvexity[{x^a, x >= 0}, x, Assumptions -> a > 0 && a <= 1]


-1

A linear function is both convex and concave.
Let us consider some integer exponents too.
FunctionConvexity[x^(2*a), x, Assumptions -> a \[Element] PositiveIntegers]


1

FunctionConvexity[{x^(2*a + 1), x >= 0}, x, 
Assumptions -> a \[Element] NonNegativeIntegers]


1

FunctionConvexity[{x^(2*a+1),x<0},x,Assumptions->a\[Element]NonNegativeIntegers]


-1

